# Distributing rows of small table based on values of a bigger table (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two tables of different lengths in Excel. The first column of the biggest table contains all the values of first column of the smaller table (and more). I would like the rows of the small table to be distributed to match the big table (creating empty rows when the values are missing). I would like to use a formula for this if possible (VBA code alternatively). I cannot do this manually because the actual tables I am working with have thousands of rows. Here are pictures describing what I am trying to do:

[Initial lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOLaN.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xdnV.png)

EDIT: I should add that the first columns of both lists in the examples are numbers, but in the real lists I am working with the values are composed of letters and numbers

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: VLOOKUP wrapped in an IFERROR will do this.

Comment: I am not familiar with these functions, how would you use them for the example I posted? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the "small" table over to make room for the results.  I put them in F and G.

Then in C1 I put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$I:$J,COLUMN(A:A),FALSE),"")
```

Copy it over on column and down the extent of the large table.

[image]

Comment: I get up to go deal with my Roomba and come back and you already have the answer posted with screen shot and an edit...apparently I need to be faster with my Roomba maintenance!

Comment: @arielle in a few minutes you will be able to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Please do so when able.

Comment: Done! Thank you for your help